# Very easy problem can't be solved by the ANN? Tensorflow Neural Net, Artificial Intelligence

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I don't understand why this enormously easy input-Output Problem can't be learned by the following ANN. I guess there is a mistake in my Code, but I don't find it.

```
X = np.array([[ 1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

Y = np.array([[ 1.,  1., -5.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
              [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
 


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])

erg = model.fit(X,Y, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)
```

Comment: A softmax activation cannot produce the values in your targets Y

Comment: Softmax prouces a vector of values in [0, 1] that sum to one, generally it only makes sense to use it for classification tasks. What kind of task is this?

Comment: I asked what task is this, classification, or regression? Accuracy is a metric valid for classification only.

Comment: No, neural networks do not work like that, if you use the one for the wrong task, it simply will not work. NNs are not magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Matias has mentioned that you are using softmax activation in the last layer and it can't be used to produce the results in your dataset, because softmax activation is useful as activation in the output layer only when you dataset targets are some kind of probabilities. Using linear instead of softmax should help.

`model.add(Dense(4, activation='linear'))`

Comment: @LukasNießen you should try for more number of epochs, lets say 300 or even 500. I'm sure it will improve and should get you the desired result.

Comment: @LukasNießen you should ```mae``` should be a better choice for model metric instead of ```accuracy``` in your case.

Comment: Accuracy as a metric is meaningless in a regression problem.

Comment: @LukasNießen Then try training for more epochs and see if mae is getting lower or not.